# OLS regression user defined function in Python

Tags: least-squares, python

Is there a way to handle complex functions for OLS regression in Python? For example, if my function is $y = a - bx^{c} + e^{dx}$, then how I can use a Python library to estimate $a,b,c$ and $d$?

i have looked at [statsmodel](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/index.html) but there isn't a way, to the best of my knowledge, to achieve this.

Comment: http://cars9.uchicago.edu/software/python/lmfit/ mentions a number of ways to do so, and extends them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, check out the `scipy.optimize` package:

```
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/optimize.html
```

Tutorial:

```
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html
```